# Como pegar um erro do backend e não deixar logar na aplicação?

Tags: python, angular, api, http, flask

Galera, boa noite, pesquisei por diversos tópicos e tentei diversas soluções e infelizmente não consegui ajustar o erro. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Angular e meu backend em Python, no momento estou fazendo a autenticação de login (sem token por enquanto), ao enviar uma requisição HTTP com username e password para o meu servidor ele checa se há registro no banco e caso exista deverá redirecionar para a rota '/dashboard', mas independente do username exisitir ou não no banco ele redireciona.
Segue abaixo linhas de código:

Meu Componente:

```
  userLogin(){
// Pegando os valores do HTML INPUT e jogando nas constantes
    const username = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    const password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

    this.authService
        .authenticate(username, password)
    .subscribe(
      () => this.router.navigate(['dashboard']),
            err => {
        console.log(this.loginForm.value)
                console.log(err);
        this.loginForm.reset();
        alert('Erro')
            }
        )
    }
```

Meu Service:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    authenticate(username: string, password: string) {    
      return this.http.post(API_URL, {"username":username, "password":password})
  }
```

Meu backend em python:

```
class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser.add_argument('username', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('password', type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args)
        password = hashlib.md5(args['password'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username = (%s) and password = (%s)"
        value = (args['username'], password)
        dbcursor.execute(sql, value)
        result = dbcursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        if len(result) > 0:
            return {"message": "user valido"}
        else:
            return {"message": "user invalido"}
```

No meu navegador eu recebo o return se o user é valido ou não e mesmo assim, independente de estar válido ou não o meu usuario é redirecionado pra rota dashboard

Comment: Olá! Para que você possa ter ajuda dos colegas, sugiro que troque suas imagens do código pelo seu código puro. O Código facilita a quem for te ajudar. Não use imagem. Coloque seu código aqui, editando sua questão e adicionado ao conteúdo. Saudações.

Comment: Olá Fabiano, obrigado pela dica, providenciando pra já!

Answer (score 2):

Tente trocar o seu subscribe por esse:

```
.subscribe((res) => {
  if(res.message == 'user valido'){
      this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
  }}
  ,(err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

      alert('erro');
}
```

Comment: Olá Veronese, não funciona dessa forma, havia tentado, mas ele não encontra o "res.message", pois não encontrar a propriedade message*

Comment: quando você da console.log(res), o que é retornado? talvez dependendo da estrutura de retorno pode ser: res.body.message

Comment: esse é meu res: {message: "user invalido"}
message: "user invalido"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Veronese, respondi à minha pergunta com o que deu certo baseado na sua ideia

Comment: @Fernando que bom que deu tudo certo.

Comment: obrigado pela luz e não pude deixar de reparar na imagem do magebot (bons tempos), sabe me informar se essa forma de autenticação q eu fiz é correta? validando pelo message enviado do meu backend?

Comment: não está errado, mas cedo ou tarde você vai precisar de retornar um token do seu backend e salvar no localStorage do frontend e então toda requisição que você fizer tem de enviar esse token, através desse token você pega os dados do usuário que requisitou aquela api. Também será necessário guardar o token pra criar um guardião de rotas, sempre que tiver um token no localStorage não deixar ir pra tela de login etc...

Answer (score 1):

Galera, consegui dessa forma, mas não sei se é a forma correta:

```
 this.authService
    .authenticate(username, password)
.subscribe((res) => {
  if(res ["message"] == 'user valido') {
    this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
  }
  else {
    console.log('user invalido')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

O melhor seria seu backend retornar 501 que é o padrão pra não autorizado e vc tratar no catch error como tinha feito.